# Invertibility of a simple matrix expression

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been stumped by a certain problem, whose essence I've boiled down to a problem in linear algebra.  Let $A$ be a real invertible matrix, and $Q$ be a real orthogonal matrix of the same size.  My question is as follows:

Is $A + Q A Q^T$ invertible?  If not, give a counterexample.  If so, can we express the inverse in terms of $A^{-1}$ and $Q$?

I'm aware that if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, then the above is true.  But I am specifically concerned about cases when $A$ is just invertible.

EDIT: As noted in the comments below, Although the Woodbury matrix identity may be of some relevance, it does not solve the problem, since it *assumes* the invertibility of $A^{-1} + Q^T A^{-1} Q$.

Comment: [Woodbury matrix identity might be of relevance here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)$$(A+QAQ^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}Q(A^{-1}+Q^TA^{-1}Q)^{-1}Q^TA^{-1}$$

Comment: @Adhvaitha, this was suggested as an anonymous edit: "Although the Woodbury matrix identity may be of some relevance, it does not solve the problem, since it assumes the invertibility of $A^{−1}+Q^TA^{−1}Q$."

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple counterexample
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \ Q = \pmatrix{0& 1\\-1&0},
$$
then
$$
A+QAQ^T = A + Q^TAQ= 0.
$$